# Upload image to .net server using POST method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to upload a `UIImage` to .Net server by converting the image into base 64 and `NSData`. But I am getting the response null. Here is my code.

```
NSString *base64Encoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
NSString *post= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myServerSideUrl?Image=%@",base64Encoded];

NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

NSString* webStringURL = [post stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSData *responseData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:urlData];

if ([response statusCode] >=200 )
{
    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
}
```

After some time, I just checked in postman showing like url too long HttpResponseCode:414. Also I tried to send the image in `NSData` format using AFNetwork, getting the same response. And I just googled about this, saying like send the base 64 string in body. When I tried to send image in body, server side can't get the image. They are creating the API like GET method but the actual method is POST. Is there any other solution about this. Any suggestions.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Not Yet. I am trying to change my backend side.

Comment: Can you post your form URL response (Get) from postman?

Comment: Sorry....And i am using POST method not GET method. but i am sending the parameters in URL like GET method.

Comment: Can you please share the code, what you have done.

Comment: How did you sent the base 64 string to backend.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting NSData to your request body without defining any key-value pair.

Try this code using AFNetworking...

```
- (void) uploadFileRequestWithHttpHeaders:(NSMutableDictionary*) headers
                          withServiceName:(NSString*) serviceName
                           withParameters:(NSMutableDictionary*) params
                             withFileData:(NSArray*) files
{

    NSString *serviceUrl = [httpBaseURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:serviceName];

    if (headers == nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *headers = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"multipart/form-data",@"Content-Type",nil];
        [self setHeaders:headers];
    }
    else
    {
        [headers setObject:@"multipart/form-data" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
        [self setHeaders:headers];
    }

    [httpSessionManager POST:serviceUrl
                  parameters:params
   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

       for (NSData *fileData in files)
       {
           [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:@"userProfileImg" fileName:@"profile_pic.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
       }
   }
                     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

                         if (success != nil)
                     }
                     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

                         if (failure != nil)
                     }];
}


- (void) setHeaders:(NSDictionary*) headers
{
    if (headers != nil)
    {
        NSArray *allHeaders = [headers allKeys];

        for (NSString *key in allHeaders)
        {
            [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:[headers objectForKey:key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
        }
    }
}

- (void) addQueryStringWithParams:(NSDictionary*) params
{
    [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:^NSString *(NSURLRequest *request, NSDictionary *parameters, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        __block NSMutableString *query = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

        NSError *err;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&err];
        NSMutableString *jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        query = jsonString;

        return query;
    }];
}
```

And call this method like this..

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"multipart/form-data",@"1.0",@"ios",token, nil];
NSArray *Keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"content-type",@"version",@"os",@"token", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *headers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:objects forKeys:Keys];

 NSMutableDictionary *paraDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [paraDic setObject:self.userNameField.text forKey:@"name"];
NSData *    userProfileImg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8f);
imageDataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:userProfileImg, nil];


[self uploadFileRequestWithHttpHeaders:headers withServiceName:@"updateProfile" withParameters:params withFileData:files];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. And i am trying to integrate your code After importing the AFHTTPSessionManager.h showing like use of undeclared identifier "httpSessionManager". Can you suggest me on this. which file i have to import.

Comment: This is just an instance which u need to declare in your class. 

/**
     *  HTTP session manager (AFNetworking Client)
     */
    AFHTTPSessionManager *httpSessionManager;
    
    /**
     *  Base URL for all http communication
     */
    NSString *httpBaseURL;

Comment: thanks again, i am implementing the service call in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. i have to upload the images one by one.so i am implementing in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.  While i am trying to implement above method undeclared identifier token and files also.

Comment: And one more thing here, i have to send the image in url only. Not in body.

Comment: Means you want to use a get request to upload the image ??

I don't think it would be possible to send image data in url.

Comment: The url will form like GET method but the actual method is POST. Any suggestions on this.

Comment: Do you have any idea to convert uiimage to bitmap

Comment: try this link to convert image into bitmap..

http://paulsolt.com/blog/2010/09/ios-converting-uiimage-to-rgba8-bitmaps-and-back

Comment: I already tried this. but no use, the file is storing in corrupted format. Showing like we can't open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code using `NSURLSession`-

```
- (void)postRequestForSubmitDataToServer {


    //Put your action URL
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"action_url.php?&attachment=att&submit=submit"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error == nil) {
            //change JSON type according to ur need.
            NSArray *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
            NSLog(@"Data = %@",JSON);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

My form data-

```
<form action="action_url.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Your Photo: <input type="file" name="attachment" size="25" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>
```

Comment: Sorry Dipankar, you didn't understand my question. My url is form like this @"action_url.php?image=%@,Submit=%@". I have to send the image in url only.Not in body.

Comment: Sorry no use. Showing like URL is too long.And one more thing need to know what is the form data.

Comment: Ok when when i am trying to hit the url getting the response null because url is breaking.Because url allows 2,083 characters. After that the url is breaking.But base 64 string consists the more than 4  lakh characters. So the url is breaking

Comment: But i am sending my base64 image to server using HTTPBody. My image length is over 200000. Though your url is like this @"action_url.php?image=%@,Submit=%@", i assume, u can send your data using HTTPBody.

Comment: Yes,url forming like GET. but when i am trying to send the image in HTTPBody the server side getting null. I know this is server side issue but i am looking for any solution about this.

Comment: Then it may be a server side problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your response.